# Counting number of records for specific ranges sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

I am trying to write a query to count the number of records based on a number of different ranges.

I have success with using `union`, but I feel there is a better way to do it.

Here is what I've done:

```
select count(col1) as range1
from tbl1
where col1 <= 15000
union
select count(col1) as range2
from tbl1
where col1 > 15001 and col1 <= 30000
union
select count(col1) as range3
from tbl1
where col1 > 30001 and col1 <= 45000
etc...
```

I am using sql server 2008.  Like I stated above, I'm positive there is a better way to do this, maybe something like this: [sql count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577155/counting-occurences-within-a-range-of-my-table-sql-server-2012),

EDIT: Yes, the database is sql 2008, and the answers below work exactly as needed. I forgot to mention that I'm actually reading a `JSON` file that has been `serialized` via coldfusion `serializeJSON`.  So in the db, everything below worked perfectly, but coldfusion query of queries doesn't support the `CASE` statement, or it doesn't appear to.

Comment: . .Your above logic does not count `15001` and `30001`.  I assume this is intentional, but you can see the comment on my answer below.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, mistake on my part.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One way is with conditional summation (for the values in separate columns):

```
select sum(case when col1 <= 15000 then 1 else 0 end) as range1,
       sum(case when col1 > 15001 and col1 <= 30000 then 1 else 0 end) as range2,
       sum(case when col1 > 30001 and col1 <= 45000 then 1 else 0 end) as range3
from tbl1;
```

Another way is with `group by` (for the values on separate rows):

```
select (case when col1 <= 15000 then 'range1'
             when col1 > 15001 and col1 <= 30000 then 'range2'
             when col1 > 30001 and col1 <= 45000 then 'range3'
             else 'other'
        end) as range, count(*) as cnt
from tbl1
group by (case when col1 <= 15000 then 'range1'
               when col1 > 15001 and col1 <= 30000 then 'range2'
               when col1 > 30001 and col1 <= 45000 then 'range3'
               else 'other'
          end);
```

I often use a subquery for this form:

```
select range, count(*)
from (select t.*,
             (case when col1 <= 15000 then 'range1'
                   when col1 > 15001 and col1 <= 30000 then 'range2'
                   when col1 > 30001 and col1 <= 45000 then 'range3'
                   else 'other'
              end) as range
from tbl1
group by range;
```

That way, the definition of `range` only appears once.

EDIT:

The above all use the logic from the OP.  However, the above logic misses the values of `15001` and `30001`.  My guess is that the OP really means `col1 > 15000 and col1 <= 30000` and `col1 > 30000 and col1 <= 45000` for the conditions.  But, I'm not changing them because the above is how the original question is phrased (perhaps there is something special about `15001` and `30001`).

Answer (score 6):

Personally I prefer using a derived (or physical) table to store my range boundaries which I then join back to in order to find my results.

I reckon the code is simpler and easier to extend if required

Something a little like this:

```
; WITH ranges (lbound, ubound) AS (
  SELECT 0, 1500
  UNION ALL SELECT 1500, 3000
  UNION ALL SELECT 3000, 4500
)
SELECT ranges.lbound
     , ranges.ubound
     , Count(your_table.value) As turtle
FROM   ranges
 LEFT
  JOIN your_table
    ON your_table.value >= ranges.lbound
   AND your_table.value <  ranges.ubound
GROUP
    BY ranges.lbound
     , ranges.ubound
```

Answer (score 3):

How about;

```
select
  count(case when col1 < 15000 then 1 else null end),
  count(case when col1 > 15001 and col1 <= 30000 then 1 else null end),
  count(case when col1 > 30001 and col1 <= 45000 then 1 else null end),
  ...
from tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

Your columns are going to all be called "range1" in being the first query in the union.

```
select count(col1) as range1
from tbl1
where 
col1 <= 15000
or
(col1 > 15001 and col1 <= 30000)
or
(col1 > 30001 and col1 <= 45000)
```

If you want separate columns, you would prefer something like so

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN col1 <= 15000 THEN 1 ELSE 0) range1,
sum(CASE WHEN (col1 > 15001 and col1 <= 30000) THEN 1 ELSE 0) range2,
sum(CASE WHEN (col1 > 30001 and col1 <= 45000) THEN 1 ELSE 0) range3
from tbl1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? I know it works out to < 15000 rather than <= 15000, but if you are talking something like currency amounts then the <= 15000 and > 15001 misses anything between those values. If the values are very large you can be talking about writing a LOT of ranges. This makes it easy to add other grouping too.

```
select cast([amount] as bigint) / 15000 * 15000, count(*)
from [transactions]
group by cast([amount] as bigint) / 15000
order by cast([amount] as bigint) / 15000
```