# Coldfusion query of queries case like statement

Tags: coldfusion

I asked this question before, and although it was answered, it really didn't solve my issue, since as far as I can tell CF QoQ doesn't support the `CASE` statement.

Here is the other question: [Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813330/counting-number-of-records-for-specific-ranges-sql-server/17813433#17813433)

So is there an easier way to accomplish what I'm trying to do, without using `CASE` statement in the sql, or am I going to have to just go back to the union style answer I originally came up with?

This is what I've come up with:

```
<cfquery name="range1" dbtype="query">
    select count(col1) as cnt
    from tbl1
    where col1 <= 15000
</cfquery>
<cfquery name="range2" dbtype="query">
    select count(col1) as cnt
    from tbl1
    where col1 <= 30000
</cfquery>
<cfquery name="range3" dbtype="query">
    select count(col1) as cnt
    from tbl1
    where col1 <= 45000
</cfquery>
<cfquery name="range4" dbtype="query">
    select count(col1) as cnt
    from tbl1
    where col1 <= 60000
</cfquery>
<cfquery name="range5" dbtype="query">
    select count(col1) as cnt
    from tbl1
    where col1 <= 75000
</cfquery>
<cfquery name="range6" dbtype="query">
    select count(col1) as cnt
    from tbl1
    where col1 > 75000
</cfquery>
```

Comment: As long as you are limited to a QoQ, then `union` is probably as clean as it gets. QoQ's are extremely rudimentary, and only meant for basic sql operations. For more complex sql operations, you will need to use a real database engine.

Comment: Tangential question... is there a reason why you'd prefer to do this in QoQ rather than on the DB?

Comment: @AdamCameron, I would prefer to query the db directly, but that isn't how I was told to do it by the higher ups.  The file that I am reading from get updated twice a day, and is serialized into a JSON, which is the file I am then deserializing, and creating my QoQ from that.  I can't change it.

Comment: Fair enough. Sometimes "the most appropriate way" is not "the best way", and a lot of factors contribute to "best" beyond coding expedience. For the record, though (and I think we agree) data-processing belongs on the server that specialises in data-processing (the DB), not a server that specialises in text-generation (a CF server). But anyway, this is a digression.

Comment: Get no argument from me! I think they are trying to make it more difficult for me.  They believe that hitting the databases as much as they think they would be hit would cause the page to load much slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The union style is appropriate, but your implementation might not be correct.  You have this:

```
select count(col1) as range1
from tbl1
where col1 <= 15000
union
select count(col1) as range2
from tbl1
where col1 > 15001 and col1 <= 30000
etc...
```

If you run that you will end up with a single column and won't be able to determine what each row represents.  Something like this would be better.

```
select 'less than 15000' range, count(col1) records
from tbl1
where col1 <= 15000
group by range
union
select '15001 to 30000' range, count(col1) as records
from tbl1
where col1 > 15001 and col1 <= 30000
group by range
etc...
```